# Function onclick makes open new link, no go to original link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `href` tag with a link to another page.

```
 <a name="mylink" class="mylink" href="path-to-new-page.html">Link to new page</a>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is that when the user clicks on the link, a onclick event is triggered. something like a return confirm.

```
onclick="return confirm('would you like to see our help center first?')"
```

If the user clicks "YES", then he is redirected to the help.html page.

If he clicks on "NO", he is sent to the link of the original `href` .

Must I use jquery for this with a popup window instead of a alert box?

Comment: jquery is just a bunch of (ultra) handy javascript functions. there's no reason you HAVE to use it to build your popup window, but you'll probably find it's much easier with jquery than without.

Comment: What you are saying is you do not want to use confirm? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Both are possible. Though personally I find alert boxes very annoying and user unfriendly. I´d use a prevent default on a click event. Then show a centered div with a grayed out background of the website instead.

Comment: That's very true actually. Showing a div will be much nicer to see for the user and not feel like a "dangerous" alert. Just prompting the user with 2 or more possibilities. This will also let me style with CSS this alert box

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question first, you do not have to, as you can get the result of the alert box inline in your Javascript.

As for the onclick on the `<a>` tag, that sounds exactly like a button. Same syntax as a link except you would do something like this:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click Here</button>
```

Then your javascript would look like:

```
function myFunction(){
    if(confirm("Would you like to see our help center first?")){
        // what happens if they select yes //
        document.href.location = "helpcenter.html";
    }else{
        // what happens if they select no //
        document.href.location = "linktarget.html";
    }
}
```

Where, of course, `helpcenter.html` is your Help Center, and `linktarget.html` is the original target URL of the link.

`confirm()` just returns a boolean on whether they pressed okay (`true`) or cancel or the `x` at the top of the dialog (`false`), and `document.href.location` is exactly the same as saying `<a href='`

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:** I used personal URLs for this demo, they may vanish in the future, but their names should still be easy to understand.*

**Without jQuery**

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('myLink');

for(var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var goToHelpCenter = confirm('Would you like to see our help center first?');
    if(goToHelpCenter){
      // Prevent the link from going to its default href
      e.preventDefault();
      // Go to help center
      window.location.href = 'http://shrt.tf/help-center.html';
    }
    // Otherwise, do nothing.
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="myLink" href="http://shrt.tf/page.html">Click me</a>
```

**jQuery version**

```js
$('.myLink').click(function(e){
  var goToHelpCenter = confirm('Would you like to see our help center first?');
  if(goToHelpCenter){
    // Prevent the link from going to its default href
    e.preventDefault();
    // Go to help center
    window.location.href = 'http://shrt.tf/help-center.html';
  }
  // Otherwise, do nothing.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="myLink" href="http://shrt.tf/page.html">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I just love Jquery!!! So simple now that I see it.  This is for sure the answer to my question. Cheers